# How to append multiple files into one file as a whole using perl?

Tags: perl

I've multiple chunk files in my Unix system. Lets say (file1.csv, file2.csv..., file10.csv). I wanted to append all these files in same order without reading them line by line.

```
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  print "$row\n";
}
```

The above sample code reads the file line by line. But the chunk files I've are having huge data. So I cannot read them line by line neither can I store it in string using `Stringify()`.

I'm looking for something in Perl similar to the below shell command.

`cat file1.csv >> file.csv`

Please let me know I can do similar copy (append at the end of target file) in Perl. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with reading and printing line by line? You can read a certain buffer size instead of reading full lines and printing that, too. Why do you not want to use `cat`?

Comment: Use `read` instead to read a block at a time.

Comment: The chunk files I've mentioned having around 20 million lines each file. So for 10 files and for each line I run a loop it takes very long time. So thought if there is any better way I could use it.

Comment: Unless you're writing portable perl code to also run on say Windows, I think you can run this faster and with less code with just `cat file*.csv > file.csv`. The `*` joker might not give you the correct order so you might have to `cat file{1..99}.csv > file.csv` instead if for example 99 is your last number. Or maybe `cat $(ls -1v file*.csv) > file.csv`. From within Perl you can run this through `system()` or `qx()`.

Answer (score 2):

As Shawn mentioned above, you can `read` a block at a time. You can experiment with different block sizes to see what is fastest on your system. For example:

```
my $BLOCK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 2;    # try reading 2 megabytes at a time
my $outfile = "output.csv";
open(OUT, ">>", $outfile) or die "Can't append to output file $outfile: $!\n";
foreach my $input_file (@input_files) {
     open(IN, "<", $input_file) or die "Can't read from input file $input_file: $!\n";
     my $data;
     my $blocks_read = 0;
     while (read(IN, $data, $BLOCK_SIZE)) {
         print OUT $data;
         $blocks_read++;
     }
     close IN;
     print "Read $blocks_read blocks from $input_file\n";
     }
close OUT;
}
```